# __bridge cast have no effect warning while using -fno-objc-arc compiler flag

Tags: objective-c, xcode, automatic-ref-counting

I'm trying to compile my code (MRC) with TTTAttributedLabel.m which uses ARC. I set -fno-objc-arc on TTTAttributedLabel.m but I'm still receiving "'__bridge' casts have no effect when not using ARC" in TTTAttributedLabel.m.

How can I safely remove this warning and compile correctly?

Comment: Don't you mean `-fobjc-arc`

Comment: Since you are turning off ARC with the `-fno-objc-arc` flag, the error makes perfect sense.